# Random numbers between 1 and 15

Tags: c++, random, bit-manipulation

I generate many many random numbers that need to be between 1 and 15 (included) in C++. Of course, I can generate zillons of 
`std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> random(1, 15);`
but this is a waste since this mersenn twister generates 32 bits (or even 64 using mt19937_64) of random values, and I would only keep 4 bits and throw away all the rest, and in my case, performance is an issue and random number generation is a significant contributor.

My idea was thus to generate for example a single 64-bit random value between 0 and 2^64-1, and select 4 bits among them. The issue is that I can't find a way to have the generated values between 1 and 15.
Example:

```
unsigned long long int r = uniform(generator); // between 0 and 2^64-1
unsigned int r1 = (r+1)&15;     // first desired random value
unsigned int r2 = ((r>>4)+1)&15; //second desired random value 
unsigned int r3 = ((r>>8)+1)&15; //third desired random value 
...
```

Here, this version of course doesn't work : despite the +1, the generated values are still between 0 and 15 (since if `r&15` happens to be `0xb1111` then adding 1 produces the result `0xb0000`).

Also, I would like the distribution to remain uniform (for instance, I wouldn't want to bias the least significant bit to occur more often, which could be the case with something like `(r&15+1)|((r&15 +1) >> 4)` since the value `0xb0001` would occur twice often).

Comment: You can still produce random number between [0-15*15*15*15[ and using `r%15 + 1`, `r/15 % 15 + 1`, `r / 15 / 15 % 15 + 1` and `r / 15 / 15 / 15 % 15 + 1`.

Comment: if it is possible to avoid divisions and modulo I would prefer .. (they are quite costly : I'm not even sure if generating four  32bit random number would be less costly than this solution with 6 divisions and 4 modulos). I'd certainly prefer bitwise operations... but for sure, if that's even remotely possible!

Comment: With constant folding, there is actually only 3 divisions. and last modulo is superfluous too. Alternatively, there is function to compute `r/15` and `r%15` at once too.

Comment: You can simply throw away any zero values. This will get you, on average, about 15 random values from each 64-bit random input.

Comment: division is slow but division by a constant can be converted to a multiplication so it'll be fast. See [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935/995714)

Comment: Distributions don't have to throw away unused bits. The `operator()` is not `const`, and therefore distributions can cache unused bits and use them on the next number generation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of

```cpp
std::mt19937 gen(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 15);

auto r1 = dis(gen);
auto r2 = dis(gen);
auto r3 = dis(gen);
auto r4 = dis(gen);
```

You might do:

```cpp
std::mt19937 gen(seed);
std::uniform_int_distribution<> dis(0, 15 * 15 * 15 * 15 - 1); // Assuming int at least 16 bits

auto r = dis(gen);

auto r1 = r % 15 + 1; r /= 15;
auto r2 = r % 15 + 1; r /= 15;
auto r3 = r % 15 + 1; r /= 15;
auto r4 = r + 1;
```

[Quick benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/CTktVvWTQShE4Xd-5e60CEP7TbU) (second version 2.5 times faster than first one)

Comment: I also tried it in the meantime and it indeed seems to be faster! thanks !

Comment: `15 * 15 * 15 * 15 - 1` is just `50624`, so you're only using 16 bits at a time. You could get 8 values from  the range 1..15 from each 32-bit value using `2562890624` as the upper bound. Or you could generate 32-bit values directly, use bit-shifting to extract 4-bit values, and manually discard any 0 values. Does `uniform_int_distribution` necessarily yield just one number from each pseudo-random 32-bit value, or is it smart enough to break it up into multiple values internally?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by [David Schwartz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721269/david-schwartz) in the comment section

> You can simply throw away any zero values. This will get you, on average, about 15 random values from each 64-bit random input.

Implementing a simple rejection sampling technique for this particular use case instead of using the more general `std::uniform_int_distribution` should be more efficient (e.g. see this [Quick Bench](http://quick-bench.com/LWwRUinxAYs3lw06ueeIfgPz9AM) comparing the standard class with the following).

```
class uniform_1_to_15_distribution
{
    uint64_t value_{};        // So that one could use std::mt19937_64 too
public:
    uniform_1_to_15_distribution() = default;

    template <class Gen> int operator() (Gen &g)
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            // When all the bits have been used (or only useless zeroes remain)
            if( value_ == uint64_t{} )
            {
                // Get a new value from the generator
                value_ = g();
                continue;
            }

            // Pick the 4 LS bits
            int ret = value_ & 0xF;

            // "Consume" the state
            value_ >>= 4;

            // Reject 0. Only value in range [1, 15] are accepted.
            if ( ret == 0 )
            {
                continue;
            }        
            return ret;
        }
    }
};
```

The distribution can be tested [HERE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MyTR2ufo5TIN4FCu).