# C++: Performance for drawing random boolean values

Tags: c++, random, boolean

I am drawing random boolean numbers with

```
std::mt19937 rng;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dis(0, 1);
```

In extreme cases, drawing these numbers can take up to 40% of the CPU time of my process. Is there any way to make this faster?

Comment: You can simply make your loop parallel.

Comment: How about drawing a number between 0 and 2^64-1, and then using one bit at a time, 64 times in a row, before calculating another random number?

Comment: If all you need is a 50/50 random number generator just use `rand`.  It's fast and you're not using it for anything cryptographic.

Comment: @Hoodi The loop was just to express that it will be use many times and because that's how I started to benchmark things. In reality my process cannot be easily parallelized (or rather it already is and can't be further parallelized)

Comment: Without the loop, we lack context. The two remaining lines of code will not take up 40% CPU time by themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would get rid of `uniform_int_distribution`.

One invocation of `std::mt19937::operator()` (i.e. doing `rng()`) will give you 32 random bits, which you can use one by one.

[A benchmark](http://quick-bench.com/SRRKBskzMBKdetfv8Cp1L4PqiCk) shows that this method is about 23 times faster.

Comment: Can also be applied to different ranges ([as 15](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56979958/2684539)) even if power of 2 seems more natural.

Answer (score 1):

You might be happy with @HolyBlackCat answer, but for sampling such values there is a Bernoulli distribution support in C++

Along the lines

```
std::mt19937 rng{1234567};
std::bernoulli_distribution bd{0.5};

std::cout << bd(rng) << '\n';
std::cout << bd(rng) << '\n';
std::cout << bd(rng) << '\n';
```