# What is the best way to generate a vector of random booleans?

Tags: c++, vector, random, boolean

I am generating a `std::vector<bool>` of random booleans.

The way I'm doing it so far is something like this:

```
   static std::mt19937 generator; 
   static std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,1);
   std::vector<bool> vec(10, false);

   for(auto val : vec) val = distribution(generator);
```

Is there a better or more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I mean if you *really* wanted you could probably just generate one int and then read a bit, shift a bit, read a bit, shift a bit... but would it be more efficient? That depends on how big this vector is going to be. If you're only making a vector of size 10, why do you care about efficiency?

Comment: "better" and even "efficient" are rather vague terms. Are you concerned about time, memory, something else? Did you measure your code and realize that it doesnt fit your needs?

Comment: FWIW I would abandon using `vector<bool>` and just use a `vector<int8_t>` or something similar.  Yeah, you don't get the space savings but it's so much easier to work with and all the "standard" techniques will work.

Comment: Also, before measuring efficiency, make sure you have enabled your compilers optimizer. Testing performance of debug builds is rather pointless.

Comment: @scohe001 Sorry, the 10 was just a random example, when it'll be user defined in my actual application, and can become quite large.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I am concerned, but not that concerned. I think my question should instead have been "Is there something drastically better than what I'm doing?" I'm new to using the random libraries in C++, so not sure if I was doing something ludicrous for something simple.

Comment: The biggest issue with what you have done is you did not seed `generator`.  If you don't seed it you'll always get the same results.

Comment: you could intialize the vector with random entries instead of first initializing with `false` and then assigning randoms, but really for a vector with 10 entries it wont make a noticable difference

Comment: Why not [`std::bernoulli_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/bernoulli_distribution)?

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for catching that!

Comment: @Evg Thanks. I was not aware that this was already implemented in `std`. What's the benefit of using this vs. what I have? Not having to do an implicit conversion from int to bool?

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 How do you initialize a vector with random entries? I don't think I also a constructor that has that capability?

Comment: For me the main benefit is more clear expression of the intent.

Comment: There is a constructor that takes a pair of iterators. You can use it to avoid redundant initialization. [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/JvvRAP).

Comment: You might be interested by result from [c-performance-for-drawing-random-boolean-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57227028/c-performance-for-drawing-random-boolean-values). There is also

Comment: @NathanOliver Do you mean if you DO seed it, you will always get the same results?

Comment: @user5965026 No, I said if you don't seed `generator`, you'll always get the same results.  A default constructed `std::mt19937` is guaranteed to produce the same results.

Comment: @NathanOliver But if you do provide a seed, don't you get the same results? Like say you have a program generating 100 random values. If you set a seed, then each time you run that program you get the same sequence of 100 values?

Comment: Well yes, you have to seed it correctly.  Normally the time is used since it changes every time the program is ran.